# How to separate the list of data into two column?

Tags: r, dataframe, text

I am trying to separate one list of data into two but I don't know how to correctly do it.

[image: This is what my data looks like]

When I use`dput(a)`My data is like

> structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
>   15L, 16L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("1\t1200.30 ", 
>   "10\t1305.80 ", "11\t1263.02 ", "12\t1312.67 ", "13\t1229.85 ", 
>   "14\t1247.43 ", "15\t1288.56 ", "16\t1287.84 ", "2\t1247.44 ", 
>   "3\t1234.20 ", "4\t1279.93 ", "5\t1249.77 ", "6\t1285.62 ", "7\t1204.17 ", 
>   "8\t1249.72 ", "9\t1245.15 "), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
>   -16L))

I want to make it as two columns like this:

```
asd  qut
1   1200.3
2   1305.80
3   1263.02
```

But I have tried to use `separate(a, into =c("asd", "qut"), sep = "\t")`, it returns

> Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a
>   character vector

Could anyone help me with it? Thank you!

Comment: If you just read it in from a file, then use `read.table("thefile.tsv")`, and it will be done right the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to specify the `col` argument that you need to specify, even if your data frame has only one column:

```
tidyr::separate(a, col = V1, into = c("asd", "qut"), sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Suggest you add the `convert = TRUE` argument to that.

Comment: Ah yes, good point, I was not aware of this argument! Thanks.